# How can I use db_delete with multiple conditions?

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to do a query like "DELETE FROM ac_journal_term WHERE jid = $jid AND tid = $tid";

```
foreach ($form_state["values"]["existing_tags"] as $tid)
{
  db_delete('ac_journal_term') 
  ->condition('jid', $jid)->condition('tid', $tid)
  ->execute();
}
```

I do not think this is the correct way to do it, but I could not find an example online on how to do multiple conditions with the db_delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

db_delete follows the usual condition conventions.

```
foreach ($form_state["values"]["existing_tags"] as $tid)
{
  $and = db_and()->condition('jid', $jid)->condition('tid', $tid);
  db_delete('ac_journal_term') 
  ->condition($and)
  ->execute();
}
```

See condition clause documentation here:

https://drupal.org/node/310086

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in block.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_delete().
 */
function block_menu_delete($menu) {
  db_delete('block')
    ->condition('module', 'menu')
    ->condition('delta', $menu['menu_name'])
    ->execute();
  db_delete('block_role')
    ->condition('module', 'menu')
    ->condition('delta', $menu['menu_name'])
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal way of doing it is -

`db_delete('ac_journal_term') 
  ->condition('jid', $jid)
  ->condition('tid', $tid)
  ->execute();`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  foreach ($form_state["values"]["existing_tags"] as $tid){
    $and = db_and()->condition('jid', $jid)->condition('tid', $tid);
    db_delete('ac_journal_term')->condition($and)->execute();  
  }
    // Above translates to:
   DELETE FROM {ac_journal_term}  WHERE ( (jid = $jid) AND (tid = $tid) )
?>
```

Please refer the following link if you need more details.
[Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_delete/7)